# Creating a generic array to utilize with hashtable in java

Tags: java, generics, hash, nullpointerexception

I understand the idea behind a hash table, but the implementation is getting frustrating. I have done some reading and gotten mixed answers. I have read that I could implement a generic array of objects as follows:

```
TableContainer[] classTable = 
    (TableContainer<Object,Object>[]) new TableContainer[256];
```

where tableContainer is:

```
class TableContainer<key,val>{
    Object key = null;
    Object val = null;
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I try to pass the following code in a function:

```
classTable[i].key = x
```

I get a null pointer exception. I understand creating generic arrays in java gets messy because of type erasure but I thought the above implementation would work. Is there any way to create a list or array of generics to be utilized as a hashtable? (no hashtable/hashmap classes permitted)

Comment: Sorry, posted the wrong line of code. The array size is 256. The problem I think I was having was that I wasn't setting my array values, I just assumed that they would be set to null based on the tableContainer constructor. I will check on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you are creating an empty array:

```
new TableContainer[0]
```

and since you cannot resize arrays over time, it doesn't have much sense. Providing that you actually create an array of some positive size, you must remember one thing: you created an array of references. And by default each array is initialized to default (zero) values, which happens to be `null` for references.

Thus you need something like this:

```
classTable = new TableContainer[8];
classTable[0] = new TableContainer();
//...later
if(classTable[0] != null) {  //will pass for [0], but not for [1]
  classTable[0].key
}
```

Comment: So do I need to create a loop that initializes every position in the classTable array to a new tableContainer? I assumed that my array initialization would do that for me, likely where I am wrong.

Comment: Works and thanks, that is what I get for making assumptions :P

Comment: @ZachCaudle: yes, you need a loop or lazily initialize every item. Otherwise the compiler would have to guess which constructor you want to use.

Answer (score 6):

You still have to initialize the object references inside the array before you can use them. Like so

```
tableContainer[] a = new tableContainer<Whatever, SomeClass>[SIZE];
for ( int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++ ) {
     a[i] = new tableContainer<Whatever, SomeClass>();
}
```

And of course, you must initialize the array to a size greater than 0, unlike you have in your example.